# PHP: select all requests OR check if any are exists

Tags: php

Is there a way to select all requests, Or check if any request is existed?

here is simple way to what I want.

### Either

`if(` all request are negatives `){` do this `}`

### Or

`if(` any request is existed `){` //do-nothing `}else{` do this `}`

### Still not clear? here is what I'm doing...

I have page I want to make it available for admins only.

```
$username_  = $_SESSION['username'];
$password_  = $_SESSION['password'];

if((!isset($username_) && !isset($password_)))
{
    if($_REQUEST['login'] !== 'no'){header("location: admincp.php?login=no");}
}
else
{
    $user_find  = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$username_."' AND password='".$password_."' AND rank='admin'");
    $user_count = mysql_num_rows($user_find);

    if($user_count == 0)
    {
        if($_REQUEST['login'] !== 'access'){header("location: admincp.php?login=access");}
    }
    else
    {
        header("location: admincp.php?login=success"); // here is the problem
    }
```

So there are three type of people:

1. not logged
2. logged not admin
3. logged and admin

so requests are for

`login=no` for `not logged`

`login=access` for `logged not admin`

`login=success` for `logged and admin` <-- admin index

in the previous code it will do as I explained, except for the last `else` part. where the problem is.

```
header("location: admincp.php?login=success");
```

here a loop is happening. and if I did this.

```
if($_REQUEST['login'] !== 'success'){header("location: admincp.php?login=success");}
```

I can't do other requests. like `$_REQUEST['add'] == 'post'`. what I need in the last `else`. I want to check if there isn't and request or not.

This is a repeat to what I said, I think now it is clear.

### Either

`if(` all request are negatives `){` do this `}`

### Or

`if(` any request is existed `){` //do-nothing `}else{` do this `}`

Comment: So basically a url parameter determines which access level you have on the admin screens? That's even worse than not escaping user input and using deprecated `mysql_` functions combined. Using plain text passwords fits somewhere in between. I think that sums up the main issues of your code.

Comment: Firstly I think it is a security risk to rely on the value of a url parameter to administer access to the admin page. It would be best to validate the user and switch on the results of your server-side validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, despite the glaring security flaw of the design, you can change your conditional to:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['login']) && $_REQUEST['login'] !== 'success'){
    header("location: admincp.php?login=success");
}
```

Overall I think a switch statement would server you better:

```
switch($_REQUEST['login']) {
    case 'no':
        //handle this case
        break;
    case 'access':
        //handle this case
        break;
    case 'success':
        //handle this case
        break;
}
```

**More importantly please do not rely on the value of a url parameter for security.**

Answer (score 1):

I think a good approach is to have a column on your table titled `permission` with values like 'admin', 'user', etc.

When the user logged in, get the column value based on the user ID and put it on a session. Then in the header use an `if` statement based on the session value that you created.  Redirect users who are not admin to user pages, and users who are not logged in to public pages.